# Java Regular expression dot

Tags: java, regex

I am confuse about java pattern matching and regular expression.
My understanding is in regular expression

"*" for Match the preceding character any number of times

"." for Any character

```
    String regex = ".ing*";  //line 1
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    String [] tests = {"ing", "ring", "trying", "running", "beings"};
    for(String test: tests) 
    {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(test);
        if(m.matches()) 
        {
            System.out.println(test + " matches " + regex);
        }
    }
```

In the upper program the output is "ring matches .ing". That's ok I understood but when I changed to line 1 like

```
            String regex = "*ing*";  //line 1      Exception occur

            String regex = ".*ing*";  //line 1      OK
```

**I want to know why exception occur that do not start with . (dot)**

Thank you very much.

Comment: `.` is a regex metacharacter.

Comment: It's regular **expression**, not regular "exception".

Answer (score 2):

There were no preceding character before the `*` in that String. If there is no preceding character before an `asterisks` then you have to escape it.

```
String regex = "\\*ing*";
                ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

At the start of this regex:

```
  String regex = "*ing*";  //line 1
```

you are saying repeat the character before the `*` as many times as needed ... *but there is no such character*, because the `*` is the first character of the regex.

There has to be a pattern of some kind before a `*` or a `+` in a regex ... otherwise it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

What your regex `.*ing*` indicates is,

[image]

From here you can see that what `.*` indicates.
`.`indicates any character